# Display flattened tree structure with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm retrieving what is essentially an album structure.

Albums can have a parent album and children albums. All the relationships will already be setup in core data.

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can display these with NSFRC. They will appear to look like a tree (they also have a depth property which I'll use to format how far they are indented in each cell), but in reality are just a flat list.

Essentially I want something like this:

```
|-album1
|-album2
|--subalbum1
|--subalbum2
|---subsubalbum3
|-album3
|--subalbum3
```

Not sure if there is a way to solve this with sorting, etc in NSFRC, at least not that my brain has come up with. Maybe a transient property on each album that references it's root album?

[image]

Comment: Does each album have an identifying number that increments for each other album (or can you add one)? What is it that defines the desired order? And you have a set maximum depth?

Comment: There is a maximum depth of 6. The root albums would probably be alphabetized by name, as would each nested group. I'm not sure I understand your first question. Albums have unique id's, but they aren't exactly based on their parent.

Comment: Could you share something about the model?

Comment: @flexaddicted Model added in question.

Comment: I guess you're using a SQLite store. You can't sort on transient attributes so that makes life difficult.

Comment: Ahhh... yes. Didn't consider that. Crapola. Guess it's time to do it the manual way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an sqlite store and you want to use NSFetchedResultsController you'll need to implement a "nested set" model [1]. Implementation is a little complicated though, so if your dataset is small enough to fit into memory it'll probably be easier to not use NSFetchedResultsController and do the sorting manually.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model